# Intuitive idea of Green's functions

Tags: soft-question, greens-function

We use Green's functions in differential equations. I also see them in electromagnetism in physics.

I would like to know the intuitive idea behind their usage/existence and why they are useful. It would be also worthwhile to add why there are so many types of these functions.

Any insights would be great.